# Casting from string to void* and back

Tags: c++, casting

is possible to re-map STL class object from void* ?

```
#include <string>

void func(void *d)
{
    std::string &s = reinterpret_cast<std::string&>(d);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hi";
    func(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&s));
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What possible reason do you have to want to `reinterpret_cast` to `void*`?  (For what it's worth, the conversion _to_ `void*` is implicit and no cast is necessary.  When casting back, `static_cast` is sufficient.)

Comment: @Nick: Lots of incorrect code appears to "work".  You *should* test code for compiler and other errors, but no error doesn't mean no problem.

Comment: @James: In actual code, `string s` is temporary which gets destroyed as soon as it is passed by the func. I was looking to bind a reference to that temporary variable which is passed by a `void*`.

Comment: You are misunderstanding at least two things there: 1) temporaries created when calling a function are not destroyed until after the function returns and 2) you can only extend the lifetime of a temporary by binding it to a reference *immediately* when it is created, not by passing it around and later binding it.

Comment: @FredNurk - I agree that in the code example shown above, variable `s` `main()` is not a temporary, but it will survive the call to `f()`. But I think the OP provided this code as a toy example for a more sophisticated use case (like, e.g., transferring an `std::string` object through the `void*` handle interface of a library component that cannot be changed). As I understand it, this question is not about lifetime but about proper casts to and fro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use static_cast to convert void pointers back to other pointers, just be sure to convert back to the exact same type used originally.  No cast is necessary to convert to a void pointer.

This works for any pointer type, including pointers to types from the stdlib.  (Technically any pointer to object type, but this is what is meant by "pointers"; other types of pointers, such as pointers to data members, require qualification.)

```
void func(void *d) {
  std::string &s = *static_cast<std::string*>(d);
  // It is more common to make s a pointer too, but I kept the reference
  // that you have.
}

int main() {
  std::string s = "Hi";
  func(&s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I re-wrote as following,

```
#include<string>

void func(void *d)
{
    std::string *x = static_cast<std::string*>(d);
/* since, d is pointer to address, it should be casted back to pointer
   Note: no reinterpretation is required when casting from void* */
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hi";
    func(&s); //implicit converssion, no cast required
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You code shouldn't compile. 
Change

```
std::string &s = reinterpret_cast<std::string&>(d);
```

to

```
std::string *s = static_cast<std::string*>(d);
```

EDIT:
Updated code. Use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: No diagnostic is required and it will compile on many compilers; reinterpret_cast is largely implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `static_cast` is enough as we deal with `void *`

Comment: ... and since you are at it, make that a `static_cast` that will help diagnose the error next time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you are trying to cast from a pointer to `void *`, then to a *reference*. The `reinterpret_cast` operator only allows casting back to exactly the same type that you started with. Try this instead:

```
void func(void *d)
{
    std::string &s = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(d);
}
```

Comment: `static_cast` would work here too. I think, your code is better than OP's exactly because it doesn't require `reinterpret_cast`, so you'd better take advatage of this!